# Accessing attribute from different model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Please take a look at this screenshot

[image]

that is the result from this

```
salesItem product_id = {{ $salesItem->product_id }}
```

and this

```
wh2summary ={{$salesItem->wh2sum}}
```

How can I access the **qty_in** in the long result from wh2sum? I can see the **qty_in** but if i do this `{{$salesItem->wh2sum->qty_in}}`

i get this error

[image]

my **Salesitems** model

```
protected $table = 'sales_items';
protected $fillable = [
    'product_id',
    'sales_id',
    'product_name',
    'product_code',
    'price',
    'rate',
    'quantity',
    'total_price',
];

public function wh2sum()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Warehouse2StockSummaries', 'product_id', 'product_id');
}
```

my **wh2sum** model

```
class Warehouse2StockSummaries extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'warehouse2_summary';
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'qty_in',
        'qty_out'
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Products', 'id','product_id');
    }  
}
```

for my **products** model

class Products extends Model
{
    // use SoftDeletes;

```
protected $fillable = [
    'product_code',
    'name',
    'categories_id',
    'wh1_limit_warning',
    'wh2_limit_warning',
    'price',
    'selling_price',
    'user_id'
];

public function warehouse2StockSummary()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Warehouse2StockSummaries', 'id', 'product_id');
}   
public function salesItem()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Purchaseitems');
}
```

please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: You get the error because it's `{{$salesItem->wh2sum}}` collection. Does `{{$salesItem->wh2sum[0]->qty_in}}` return you something?

Comment: yes it does @senty :) Thanks a lot!